# Is it possible to have SVCUtil generate the service and data contract only, but not the client and channel objects

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I want to use svcutil to generate only the interface for the service contract, and the corresponding data contracts for the inputs and outputs.

However, I want to prevent svcutil from generating the Service Clients and Channel.  Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same boat at you.  Take a look at this tool http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/ there's an option for service-side stub that will skip all the ClientBase stuff generated by SvcUtil.
Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer:
You can use the "/dataContractOnly" option to only generate the data contracts for a service. However, this won't create the service contract, like you're looking for.

Depending on the footprint of the service, it may be a simple process to simply remove the generated channel and client code, from the output file(s).

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but it's a manual process.  I want to be able to tap into svcutil to auto-gen contracts, but not the clients.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to exclude them? Can't you just ignore them and use your own contract implementations?

Comment: Yes, I want to have one library that exposes the interface for the service and its data contracts.  The other library would contain the implementation of these interfaces, such as a service invoking implementation, or service client.

Comment: How is this a partial answer?   It addresses the EXACT problem Oved is trying to solve.